# One-to-many validation race condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, race-condition

I have two entities with one-to-many relationship.

**TripRequest.cs**

```
public class TripRequest
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public Guid TripId { get; set; }
    public Trip Trip { get; set; }
}
```

**Trip.cs**

```
public class Trip
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection <TripRequest> Requests { get; set; } = new List<TripRequest>();
}
```

And I have a command in which I want to check that the trip does not contain other requests from the user.

```
public void Handle(CreateRequestCommand command)
{
    var trip = _tripRepository.GetWithInclude(t => t.Requests)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(command.TripId));

    if (trip == null)
    {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    }

    if (trip.Requests.Any(x => x.UserId.Equals(command.UserId)))
    {
        throw new ConflictException();
    }

    var request = new TripRequest
    {
        TripId = command.TripId,
        UserId = command.UserId,
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now
    };

    _requestRepository.Create(request);
}
```

There is a race condition when the check was passed in stream A and the user was added in stream B. Next, a user with the same UserId is added in stream A.

I tried to use ConcurrencyCheck attribute and I'm thinking about composite key for TripRequest.
Is it possible to do such check on database side? What is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: You have to give some more context. What do you mean by a "stream"? What kind of application is this? Something CQRS-based? Then, what is `trip` an what kind of method is the code snippet from, what's its purpose? And which EF version?

Comment: @GertArnold Web (rest api), CQRS, EF Core 5.0. Code snippet from command handler (see above, updated). Purpose of the command is to add a travel request which can then be accepted or rejected by the organizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be treating this as a concurrency problem because you can use a unique constraint/unique index to absolutely prevent having two TripRequests for the same (TripId,UserId), eg:

```
[Index("UserId","TripId",IsUnique = true)]
public class TripRequest
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public Guid TripId { get; set; }
    public Trip Trip { get; set; }
}
```